# Data Structure pseudo code

Tags: data-structures, pseudocode

Write the pseudo code to print diamond of asterisks  as given below.  Code should  prompt for 
an integer value which will serve as the number of asterisks across the middle of a figure which 
has the appearance of a diamond.  It should print the figure. Example: Width of diamond --> 5

```
     *
   * * *
 * * * * *
   * * *
     *
```

Comment: stck overflow isn't a code generator

Comment: Well, write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    *
  * * *
* * * * *
  * * *
    *
```

To get such output :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n/2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n/2-i; j++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; j++){
        cout << "*";
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < n/2-i; j++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
for(int i = 0; i <= n/2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < n-2*i-2; j++){
        cout << "*";
    }
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```